What happens when a car starts moving? The last moment the car is at rest versus the first moment the car moves
Imagine a car that's at rest and then it starts moving. Consider these two moments:

The last moment the car is at rest.
The first moment the car moves.

The question is: what happens between these 2 moments? It might sound like a silly question and it probably is: my physics teacher asked us this question years ago and never gave us the answer. Apparently the answer "the 2 moments coincide" was not a valid answer.
I recently learned that he passed away so I will never know if he was just teasing us or if it was a reasonable question. Do you know what the answer might be?

It's worth noting that there's really nothing special about the car in this example, because the car was never really at rest relative to someone looking at the solar system from afar and seeing it going around the sun, the spin of the earth, etc. The question may well be what happens when a body changes its velocity with respect to a certain frame, which is all that's really happening here.

I wonder if this was poorly worded (or remembered) and the intent was to ask what happens between the start of force being applied and the start of movement, which might be the overcoming of static friction?

Did your teacher reject that answer because it was  untrue or because it was incomplete? this was at high school? I get the feeling that Qmechanic may have leaked the answer in their editing of tags.

I remember well the question and it was exactly how I worded it. But it could very well be about friction, @DanGetz. And yes, it was at high school. I remember I gave him two answers: both "the 2 moments coincide" and "something goes to infinity" (I was just a kid..). He replied with a smile and repeated the question. He never gave us an answer and I ended up forgetting about it...

Reminds me of the bump function, where the function and all derivatives are continuous at 1.0 (first moment the car moves).

Mathematically, both of those moments cannot exist separately.  A "moment" is instantaneous which means that it is a point in time and thus has no time-length of its own.  And because Time is defined (classically) as being continuous, consequently there cannot be two adjacent moments/points in time, there must always be moments/points in-between any two other moments.  But you have given a definition of two points that requires that they be adjacent (because there is no possible intermediate state between them).  Therefore your question is paradoxical: i.e., it is self-contradictory.

@JánLalinský the change in velocity would come when the acceleration changes from zero to non-zero so it should be well defined.

@MarkRansom No, the time instant with jump in acceleration does not coincide with finite change in velocity. Velocity is still zero, so it is a moment where the car is still at rest. It isn't at rest at later instants, but due to continuity, no such instant is first.

Maybe your teacher was trying to make you think and make up your own definitions and answer. For example, how can we define "the last moment the car is at rest", and "the first moment the car moves"? The first is the maximum of times for which $v=0$, so mathematically it can exist. The latter is problematic: if times were discrete, then there could be a first instant in the sequence for which speed isn't zero. But if time is continuous, which is standard in physics, then no time instant of the motion is first. So my answer would be, the second is not defined.

I explore a similar issue in this question.  An event which is typically regarded as instantaneous but is not on closer inspection.  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/627943/how-many-derivatives-for-the-position-of-an-object

This is not so much a physical problem but one of pure mathematics, viz. the concept of real numbers. You might as well ask, "what is the first number that is $>0$", and realize (pun intended) what mess you got yourself into.

You are asking about a real world problem. We describe the real world using physics. But the universe may or may not exactly follow the physical description we assign to it. So , with our current theories of calculus and physics, the answers are written below.But what exactly is the reality cannot be known. We cannot prove that quantities in universe works the way our mathematical number systems do. But we can assume this.

I’m voting to close this question because it is based on the false premise that moments 1 and 2 exist.

@WillO I just looked at the list of valid reasons to close a question and being based on a false premise is not one of them. It is however a valid answer, if you explain why moments 1 and 2 do not exist.

Closing a question with over 4,000 views, 23 upvotes and 17 answers, for a tenuous reason, could be considered inconsiderate and antisocial, but I don't see anything in the rules about that, so you you are entitled to be that way if you wish.

@DanGetz (was) "the intent was to ask what happens between the start of force being applied and the start of movement, which might be the overcoming of static friction?" A conundrum still exists if we ask what happens between an instant when an accelerating car was moving at any given velocity and earliest instant when the car was moving at a greater velocity. Static friction becomes irrelevant.

@KDP :  So if someone asks a question that begins by reminding us that all real numbers are less than 1000 and then asks how this affects the trajectory of a cannonball, what should the close reason be?

A valid answer would be to point out that not all real numbers are less than 1000. The question can perhaps be amended and cleaned up, which is what the comment section is for. Why is it you see the only solution as closing the question? It's a bit like saying we have found this person guilty of jay walking. How should we execute him? If every person that asked questions had no misconceptions and absolute clarity on the current accepted state of physics, they wouldn't really need to be asking questions.

Suppose the last moment the car was at rest is at $t_0=0$. What time is the first moment the car moves?
Suppose you pick some number $t_{first} > 0$. It doesn't matter what number you pick. You can always show that there is a problem with it.
There is a number $t_{first}/2$. This number is bigger than $0$, so it is after $t_0$. So the car is not at rest. It is before $t_{first}$, so the car has not started moving yet.
This is a contradiction. It shows you cannot pick a moment after $t_0$ that is the moment the car first moves. You must conclude the car starts moving at $t_0$. So you are right to be suspicious of his answer.

This question is continuing to generate interest, so I thought I would add to my answer.
First numbers make a difference. This paradox was first proposed by Zeno. It wasn't settled for thousands of years. But it is quite straightforward to modern mathematicians.
That said, you still have to be careful with it. I haven't been careful enough. The resolution I proposed is that at $t = t_0$, the car is both at rest and has started moving. This sounds like a paradox.
That's OK - I'm a physicist. The purpose of physics is to model the behavior of the universe. A logical inconsistency this small doesn't change the predicted behavior of the car at all. Physicists make bigger approximations all the time.
But it isn't good enough for a mathematician. Mathematicians model ideas. Logic is their only tool. If the logic isn't airtight, a false statement can be proven. And one false statement can be used to prove more. The entire structure of mathematics would collapse.
So a mathematician would pay more careful attention to definitions. What exactly is meant by "at rest", or "has started moving"? Is the car at rest if its position hasn't changed? If its velocity is $0$?
He would note that I haven't really proven that the car has started moving at $t_0$. Just at all times after $t_0$. There is no such thing as the first moment where the car's position has changed. There is only a last moment where it has not.
This kind of distinction is crucial to point set topology. It determines many interesting properties of topological spaces.  (Where but CalTech would an introduction like the link come from the Division of Humanities and Social Studies?)

This description made me think of Zeno's paradoxes, and I think OP's teacher might have either created or stumbled upon a variant of one them - probably the arrow paradox.

How did you arrive at your conclusion that they must coincide? If anything, you just showed that one of the two is ill-defined, i.e. if the last moment at rest is defined, then there is no first moment (minimal time) that the car is moving. A car cannot simultaneously be moving and not moving.

I guess this is what he had in mind when he asked us this question. I just hope that other students to whom he asked the same question (and possibly gave the answer) see this post and reveal what was in his mind. The man was very smart so I would really like to know.

@PasserBy You are presuming that rest (not moving) can be instantaneously distinguished from moving.  "Move or not" isn't a property of an instant, it is a property of an interval.  If for all intervals of time immediately before an instant you are still, and all intervals of time immediately after an instant you are moving, it is a matter of choice of definition if you are moving in intervals surrounding that instant.

@Yakk No, we're obviously talking about an idealized situation, one which you model the speed of the car with some function $v(t)$ which certainly has a defined value for every point.

Not sure how this resolves anything. If t0 is the time when the movement starts, what is the last time it is not moving?

@PasserBy With different frames of references it can. To the people in the car, the car doesn't move, the world around them does. To those standing outside the car looking at it, the car moves but the world stays still.

@PasserBy I mean, in my idealized situation, I'm doing constructive mathematics.  In which real numbers don't have an general equality operator.  However, in a more general situation, the concept of "velocity" is "change in position over a change in time", and at an instant there is no change in time - you can take the limit (which is what calculus does), but the result is the limit of the concept, which may or may not align with the concept.  Here, you are going to either have an undefined velocity, or a period with a non-zero velocity indistinguishable from zero.

@Yakk In an instant, where there is no flow of time, any property of time is invalid. It isn't just undefined, its inapplicable to ask. An instant is a model that excludes the time dimension.  You cannot have a velocity in an instant, so it cannot be defined just like the distance you have to walk to tomorrow will always be undefined. Velocity is replaced by mass, inertia and direction. The instant before the car moves there is a cause in motion, the next instant begins the reaction with the car moving. Any more details will likely lie in the answer to the fine-structure constant.

@Yakk In classical mechanics, the state space is spanned by the positions and momenta of all objects. So in that sense there is certainly a difference between an object and rest and an object in motion even if you only consider a single point in time. In the first case the momenta will be zero, whereas in the second case they won't. In quantum mechanics, things get a bit more complicated because of uncertainty. But at least if you consider the wave function a physical entity, then more or less the same argument as for classical mechanics applies.

@DavidS You know that's not what Passer By meant by "a car cannot simultaneously be moving and not moving" in this context, there's an implicit "in the same frame of reference" there. :P (And besides, simultaneity doesn't exist across differing frames of reference, so I'd say that's still not an example~)

if $t_1$ is the first moment the car start moving and you conclude $t_1= t_0$, it follows that $t_1-t_0 = 0$. if we pick the next moment $t_2$ after the car starts moving the same logic tells us $t_2 = t_1$ and $t_2-t_0 =0$. After n intervals we have $t_n-t_0 =0$, so we are forced to conclude the car cannot move no matter how large n is.

This is a version of Zeno's arrow paradox. One solution is to reject the implied dichotomy of "at rest" or "moving" and say that there is a time $t$ such that for all times before $t$ the car is at rest and for all times after $t$ the car is moving but that at the moment $t$ itself the car is neither at rest nor moving. There is therefore no last moment when the car is at rest, and no first moment when it is moving.
This like saying that there is no largest negative real number and no smallest positive real number because in between the negative and the positive numbers there is a number zero that is neither negative nor positive.
Of course, there is no single "right" answer to this type of question - your teacher's goal when asking the question was to get you to think about the nature of time and the nature of movement, and he has clearly succeeded since since you still remember the question.

Can we say that at exactly $t$, the car is indecisive as in rest of motion and the question cannot be answered because motion or rest can only be determined for a time interval instead of just and instant.

@Proscionexium Yes, that would be another possible solution.

@Proscionexium It's not because "motion or rest can only be determined for a time interval instead of just an instant". The concept of instantaneous velocity is perfectly acceptable to discuss at a zero-duration instant. For any t>0, the car is moving, whether we choose a non-zero interval or not. Saying "we can't answer" whether the car is moving or not at t=1 is simply incorrect (the car is clearly moving), even though we're talking about an instant and not a time interval.

@NuclearHoagie I get it now. So the problem is just trying to fill the gap between motion and rest although there ain't a gap at all.

@NuclearHoagie "The concept of instantaneous velocity is perfectly acceptable to discuss at a zero-duration instant." I agree it is a concept we can discuss but I am not aware of any way to actually measure speed without an interval of time being involved.

@JimmyJames It's true you cannot measure velocity from a photograph, and any physical measure of velocity must be over a non-zero duration. But that doesn't make the concept of instantaneous velocity useless or invalid - velocities are not simply "undefined" over zero-length intervals. Not quite sure what you're getting at, we don't need to be able to physically measure instantaneous velocity at t=1 to conclude that it exists and is non-zero.

@NuclearHoagie The point is that it's a logical argument but it is not falsifiable.  No one can set up an experiment that shows what is happening at a 'moment'.  A 'moment' is a conceptual idea that we know cannot be shown to exist.

@NuclearHoagie To find the velocity from the position, you need to take its time derivative. A derivative requires the function to be defined on a neighborhood of the point of interest. A single point in time is insufficient. So you need to know the position for at least two different times.

@JimmyJames Perhaps it is safe to say that an instantaneous velocity is just over an infinitisimal interval which is why it is instantaneous yet technically over an interval that is just too small.

If the state of a system is defined at an instant then momentum is also defined at an instant. If the state of the system is only defined over an interval then you will need to find another definition of the state and write the laws of physics in some manner other than differential equations.

Your answer is entirely reasonable - the two moments coincide. There is no physical sense of "between" two time points that have arbitrarily little duration between them. There is no point in time where the car has ceased being at rest, but has not yet started moving. There are only two mutually exclusive states, the car cannot be both not at rest and unmoving.
"Between" is the wrong word to use. We can talk about what happens "at" the moment the car stops being at rest and start moving, since that is all one moment. At that moment, quite simply, the car starts moving.
To put it another way, consider that two values separated by an infinitesimal difference are actually exactly equal to another (as described here). For any duration you could suppose between when the car stops resting and when it starts moving, we can observe there is no such transition that takes that long - the duration between the two time points is infinitesimally small, therefore, the two time points are the same. They're just different ways of naming the same time point - it's a bit like asking what happens between 12:00PM and noon. The concept of "between" requires two distinct objects and is semantic nonsense when applied to only one object. The aforementioned question is more clearly nonsensical when rephrased as "what happens between noon and noon?".

And yet, the car being at standstill and the car being in motion seem like two fundamentally different things. Also, and relatedly, I contest your notion that $\lim_{x\to 0} x$ is zero. What we have here is a procedure which allows us to get as close as we desire. $\lim_{x\to 0} x = 0$ is a simplified notation for that.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica The limit does exist, and the limit (not x) is indeed equal to exactly zero. A limit doesn't tend toward a value, a limit is a value. The limit of x as x approaches zero is exactly zero, not some number arbitrarily close to zero, or something that "tends toward zero". It's just zero. There is nothing "between" the left-handed limit as x approaches 0 and the right-handed limit as x approaches 0, since both of those are equal to exactly 0.

Yes, I was imprecise. The limit is indeed zero, that is what it means; my fault. x is never zero though, which in this case means the points in time never coincide (even if we assume non-granular time which is probably wrong).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Two values separated by an infinitesimally small difference are exactly equal to each other (https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/26934/to-17-year-olds-how-can-i-explain-that-two-numbers-with-arbitrarily-small-diffe) For any non-zero duration time period we could suppose between "stops resting" and starts moving", we can observe there is no transition period that takes that long - the time difference between "stops resting" and "starts moving" is infinitesimal, therefore, the times at which the car "stops resting" and "starts moving" are indeed the same.

The two moments you mention are not special. You can ask the same question about any other pair of speeds that are infinitesimally close. For example, you can consider the last moment when the car wasn't going more than ten miles an hour and the first moment that it was. Given that, it is wrong to consider them to be the same moment. To see why, consider a series of infinitesimally close speeds, and label them S0, S1, S2, S3 and so on. If you consider that the car is going at S0 then S1 'in the same moment', then you have to apply the same argument to S1 and S2, then to S2 and S3 and so on, which leads you to the obviously false conclusion that the car is going at all speeds at once. If you want a proper understanding of the principles involved here, you are really talking about the fundamentals of calculus, since that's how you are modelling the acceleration of the car.
Of course, all of what I have just said is a huge simplification anyway. If you really were to zoom-in in terms of time to examine the motion of the car over a phenomenally short timescale, you would find that it was never completely still to begin with. The constituent atoms and molecules of the car would all be vibrating randomly with heat energy, and as the car did start to accelerate it would not do so monolithically- instead it would behave in an hugely complicated way, with the movement of some parts lagging behind that of others.

There's a fundamental problem with this question that makes it unanswerable in real physical terms.  To understand why, we need to think about physics for a moment and how mathematical models are not reality (the map is not the territory.)
Let's start with some basic concepts.  Movement is a change of location. Movement inherently requires the passage of time.  Speed is (in this context) the rate of movement over time.  So, when we say something is moving or has moved, what we mean is that at time A, an object was at a certain location and at time B, it was at some other location.  So, another way to ask your question is "at what time did the speed of the car go from 0 to something more than 0?"
It's fine to come up with logical arguments about this and there's a long history of that.  But physics is not just logical arguments and math problems. What distinguishes physics (and science in general) is empirical observations.
How can we experimentally determine when this movement starts?  One option would be to set up a video camera with a known frame rate.  We can examine the frames and at find the first one where the vehicle's position has changed.  Great. But there's a problem: we only know which interval the movement started.  That is, we know that movement started between when that frame was taken and when the prior frame was taken.  But during that interval, we have the exact same problem as we started with.  So, we get a high-speed camera and shorten the interval.  We get an even faster camera.  We use a laser instead.  We keep working to make the interval smaller.  Ultimately, though, we hit the limits of precision of our technology.  No matter how precise the technology is, though, we will still only identify an interval, not a moment.
And mainstream physics says this isn't just a limit of our current technology, but rather a fundamental aspect of nature.  There's simply no way to take a measurement without some finite interval of time.  The best we will ever be able to say is that at time A it was at position X and at time B it was at position Y.  What happens during that smallest measurable interval of time is a matter of conjecture.

Let me add this. We are so accustomed to represent physical quantities with real numbers that we do not even think about it. Reals are a great abstraction, but somehow they are too "fine grained" for physics or anything "real world" for that matter. There are no physical measurements where we get the full spectrum of real numbers. This leads to paradoxes like this one or paradoxes about probabilities.

@g.kertesz I might be taking this too far, but I think the Banach-Tarski ("a pea can be chopped up and reassembled into the Sun") is a good example of how infinitesimals don't make sense in physical reality.


Imagine a car that's at rest and then it starts moving. Consider these two moments:
The last moment the car is at rest.
The first moment the car moves.
The question is: what happens between these 2 moments?

Note, this is a math puzzle, not a physics puzzle.

Apparently the answer "the 2 moments coincide" was not a valid answer

That is correct. "The 2 moments coincide" is not a valid answer. The key error is assuming that both of those moments exist in the first place. Because the question assumes both exist, it is a trick question. It is possible for one or the other to exist, or neither, but not both.
At some moment, $t$, "the car is at rest" means $v(t)=0$ and "the car moves" means $v(t)\ne 0$ where $$v(t)=x'(t)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h}$$ So then "the last moment the car is at rest" is $\max\{t|v(t)=0\}$ and "the first moment the car moves" is $\min\{t|v(t)\ne 0\}$
In order for this limit to exist the position $x(t)$ must be differentiable. Not all functions are. If $x(t)$ is not differentiable then there is no max or min $t$ as described above.
For example, if we imagine (since this is a math exercise rather than a physics exercise) that $$x(t)=\begin{cases}
 t & 0\leq t \\
 0 & t<0
\end{cases}$$For this function, the above limit does not exist at $t=0$ so $v(0)$ is undefined, meaning for $t=0$ the car cannot be said to be moving, nor can it be said to be at rest. The car is not moving for any negative $t$, but there is no maximum negative number so there is no last moment that it is at rest. The car is moving for any positive $t$, but there is no minimum positive number so there is no first moment that it is moving.
Imagine instead that $$x(t)=\begin{cases}
 t^2 & 0\leq t \\
 0 & t<0
\end{cases}$$ this function is differentiable at $t=0$ with $v(0)=0$, meaning the car is not moving for any non-positive $t$, and the car is moving for any positive $t$. The maximum non-positive number is $0$ so the last moment the car is at rest is $t=0$. There is no minimum positive number, so there is no first moment that the car is moving.
At any $t$ such that $x(t)$ is differentiable, then $v(t)$ will have one and only one value. That value will either be zero or it will be non-zero, but not both. So any given $t$ cannot both be the first moment that it moves and the last moment that it does not move. Therefore, "the 2 moments coincide" is indeed an incorrect answer to a trick question.

You have entered a rabbit hole that kept physicists and philosophers arguing for ages.
The desciption you gave of a car at rest is a classical description in terms of Newton's mechanics. If we assume continuous values for position and velocity, the question of "between moments" becomes ill-defined, since there is no positive real number "next to 0", as others pointed out.
Quantum mechanics, however, gives a different description, where particles do not have position and momentum vectors of infinite precision. Even the lowest energy state is not exactly zero, some positive amount of zeropoint energy remains. We also can't cool particles down to 0 Kelvin and stop them for the same reason. In essence, nature solves this conundrum by making sure nothing is ever at rest. Everything is vibrating all the time.
Respect to your professor for giving young minds a tough nut to crack. Respect to you for still pondering it.

The other thing that QM seems to do that helps here (maybe what you are saying) is that it implies at least some level of discreteness at the smallest scales.  The whole "keep dividing in half to infinitum" only presents as a problem when we assume continuity. In the way a film or video is really a series of discrete frames that appear to be smooth and continuous, I think the concept of continuous movement may be an illusion.

If your teacher does not accept "the two moments coincide" as an answer, then maybe your teacher believed in infinitesimals. Someone made sense of non-standard analysis, but it is not usually used in mathematics.

The car, like almost everything else, is always moving. Or all the bits of it are anyway. When it starts to get going all in one particular direction, some of it will start to get going before the rest of it. So it probably does make sense to talk of a period between the last point when none of it was going in any particular direction (aka 'not moving' when considered on a grander scale), and when all of it was first going in one particular direction. The same would apply to a golf ball being hit. The side towards the golf club gets moving first, deforming the ball, whilst the side away from the club remains more or less stationary for a very small amount of time.

Surely in order to define something as moving, there needs to be $2$ places at $2$ times? The whole concept of movement is a transfer from place $X$ to place $Y$.
If you measure an object at one time only, $t_1$, then you cannot know if it is moving or not. There is no speed, because $$\text{speed} = \frac{\text{distance}}{\text{time}},$$ and distance requires two places, $\mathrm{P_1}$ and $\mathrm{P_2}$
Or have I missed something?

This is essentially a TL;DR of Dale's  version:
If the velocity $v(t)$ is a continuous function in the time $t$ (which is plausible for a car with limited accelearation), then $v^{-1}(0)$ is a closed set as the preimage of a closed set. The last moment the car is not moving (i.e. the velocity is zero) is then well defined
$$
\max v^{-1}(0) = \max\{t\in \mathbb{R}: v(t)=0\},
$$
assuming the car does not stop again later. Whereas the first moment the car is moving is ill defined as $v^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0)$ is an open set as the preimage of an open set. It therefore has no minimum (first moment the car is moving). Its infimum is well defined and coincides with the last moment the car is moving.

For an object to be at rest one must be referring to some frame of reference.
A car may be stationary in frony of you while it is rotating around the earth's axis once per siderial day, orbiting the sun once per year, and orbiting the galactic centre. All these can be ignored by choosing a frame of reference where the car's location relative to you with time remains fixed.
If we ignore non-Newtonian mechanics, and it's reasonably safe to assume that your teacher was not intending to invoke relativity, then.
Velocity change = acceleration x time.

IF you treat the passage of time as linear and continuous then there is NO time period between being stationary and moving. If the teacher did not accept that answer then two alternatives come to mind. There will be others. ALL will be somewhat pedantic, but all will help expand your thinking processes :-).
Time is for practical purposes quantised.The shortest time period that 'exists'  is Planck time = 5.39E-34 second.  During this rather small period, if step pure force is applied unioformly to an "ideal car" then the state of motion of the car can not be determined until 1 Planck Time has elapsed.
Note that this is a simplistic and somewhat stupid answer but MAY be what he had in mind.
This brings us to another alternative.
I mentioned an "ideal car".
They are hard to come by.
A non ideal car is compressible, and has distributed mass.
Forces applied to it by gravity and propulsion system and reactive friction, stiction, aerodynamics once any part of it starts to "move" and more will mean, that when observed closely at very high frame rates, it "lurches" into motion. It will transition from being best described as stationary to being best described as moving. There is no certain absolute boundary if you insist on looking and measuring closely enough.
In practice such precise inspection is very very seldom of value, and we may say eg "when the wheels first start to move detectably" that it is in motion.
This also is only possibly hatw your teacher had in mind, but it has achieved the desired aim of getting you thinking.
And getting us thinking as well.
Your teacher would have been pleased :-) .

Isn't the Planck time more like the shortest time interval that can be accurately measured?  I think there's a good distinction between that and saying only discrete time "exists", and the difference seems to lead to confusion.

@JMac  No. Yes. :-) - "The laws of Physics" [as we know them, Jim] do not apply for shorter periods. Better reference than above here. https://wiki2.org/en/Planck_units

Right, we know it's a limit where known theories fall apart, but that's more due to theoretical limits of quantum measurement, and because we have no proven theory to reconcile QM and small scale gravity.

The question can be answered in a great many ways, and I feel sure the teacher was not looking for a "correct" answer but to see how you responded to it. I think he hoped you would challenge the question and that this would lead into a discussion of the importance of precise definitions. Most important to him might have been that cause and effect are never simultaneous, and that thought itself could be explored at many levels, as has been demonstrated in several answers.


Apparently the answer "the 2 moments coincide" was not a valid answer.

Lets consider the event ($x_0, t_0$) when the car was last stationary and ($x_1, t_1$) when the car was first moving. If $t_1 = t_0$ and $x1>x_0$ then we have $v = \delta x/\delta t = \infty$ which violates special relativity. If $x1=x_0$ then we have $v = \delta x/\delta t = 0/0$ which is indeterminate, but it also implies that event ($x_0, t_0$) is the same as event ($x_1, t_1$) and that they are in fact the same event and no motion has occurred. This is perhaps what your teacher was getting at when he said ""the 2 moments coincide" is not a valid answer. This paradoxical situation arises if we consider time and space to be infinitely divisible.
Calculus tells us we can assign an exact velocity value to an exact instant of time. That means we can ascribe a velocity of zero at instant zero and a non-zero value of velocity at a later instant. To say there is a zero interval between time zero and the next instant is to imply the velocity at time zero is both zero and non zero, which is illogical. If we assume a time $t_1$ which is the smallest time greater than $t_0$, we can always halve that value and find a smaller time. Let's assume at some small finite time, the time interval $\delta t_n$ is described by some fraction $\frac1{2^{n}}$, where n is an integer. As n goes to infinity, the interval goes to zero, but implicit in this assumption is that we can arrive at infinity by continuously doubling a number, which is of course nonsense.
In physical reality, one explanation is the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. This principle tells us the more certain we are about the momentum of a particle the less certain we can be about its position and vice versa. This means if we are absolutely certain a particle is stationary, we have a huge uncertainty in the particles position at time zero and if we are absolutely certain of a particle's location at time zero we have a huge uncertainty in its velocity. This make it impossible to say a particle is stationary at some exact instant, so the question in the title becomes almost impossible to define.
Almost all the paradoxes ascribed to Zeno are based on what would happen if we assume space and time are infinitely divisible. The Achilles and the tortoise paradox and the dichotomy paradox (and the question the OP) can be boiled down to whether or not the infinite sum $$\frac12 +\frac14+\frac18+\frac1{16}+ ...$$ is equal to 1. Almost universally, the modern interpretation is the infinite sum is exactly equal to one. It can be shown that for a finite series of terms the sum can be written as:
$$ S_n = 1 +\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$
For $n = \infty$ we get:
$$ S_{\infty} = 1 +\frac{1}{2^{\infty}} $$
and as n approaches infinity, the term
$ \frac{1}{2^{\infty}} $ approaches 0 and so $S_n$ approaches 1.
Is this the same thing as saying the gap between one and the previous term is exactly zero and $S_n$ is exactly one?
The concept of surreal numbers would beg to differ. The Wikipedia article states (paraphrased) that infinitesimal numbers are smaller in absolute value than any positive real number. In other words there is a surreal number ($1/\infty$) between the smallest real number and zero and therefore the gap between the smallest real number and zero is not zero and this is basically the answer to 'What happens between the last moment the car is at rest and the first first moment the car moves?'. Also note that in the set of surreal numbers, the number $1/\infty$ is not equal to zero. In fact in this Numberphile video, Donald Knuth states there an infinite number of surreal numbers between any two real numbers, but what does he know?
Should we dismiss surreal numbers out of hand? After all, how can we discuss what is between the smallest real number and zero if we cannot define what the smallest real number is? Whatever we define it to be, we can always divide it half again and find a smaller real number. If I wanted to be awkward I could say, first tell me what the smallest positive real number is, before we discuss what is between the smallest
positive real number and zero.
We can note that all of Zeno's paradoxes that involve motion or time, e.g. the Achilles and the tortoise paradox, the dichotomy paradox or even the arrow paradox, can be resolved if we assume there is an minimum indivisible discrete unit of time, possibly much smaller than the Planck interval. Unfortunately we are unable to probe down to that level and so there is no measurement we can perform to support or refute that idea.
Unfortunately I cannot provide a definitive answer to the OP and my personal belief is that there is no definitive answer, but I should stress that the majority accepted answer is that there is a definitive answer to the OP question (and Zeno's paradoxes) which is based on the premise that the infinite sum 1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+... is exactly equal to 1 and that $1/\infty$ is exactly equal to zero, but to me, this implies that the gap between the smallest real number and zero is exactly zero. To me, the issue is not clear cut.

Are you sure the question was intended in such a philosophical manner?
It can be deconstructed into ordinary high-school level physics:
Let's replace the car in our mind with any dumb block. The block "rests" (isn't moving in relation to our reference frame) either because there is no force applied to it at all, or because the force applied to it is less than the friction force. The applied force is not completely lost, it goes into internal deformations, even if we can't see it.
The applied force and the friction force are in static equilibrium. There is no notion of time, the force is either smaller than the friction, or it is larger.
Let's assume the force is continously increasing over time. Then there will be a momenent in time when the applied force overcomes the friction and the object would then start to be accelerated. Any infinitesimal amount of time after that leads to an increase in velocity v=a*t where the acceleration a comes from the applied Force a = (F_applied - F_roll)/m which is still reduced by the roll friction.
It felt to me that this was missing from the other answers. So again, time enters only because the force is changing. If it is not changing, the object/car either moves or doesn't move.
In the case of the car, it is the motor that is increasing the force applied to the wheels. There is no first moment of movement, any infinitesimal amount of time after the applied force has overcome the friction force results in a correspondingly small increase in velocity.
What happens between these 2 moments?
High-school level answer: The applied force has overcome the friction force.

The apparent contradiction arises because of the simplicity of the physical model when thinking of the car as a single object.
In reality, the car (or any object) is never at rest, when you consider all of the particles at atomic/sub-atomic level: they're all continuously moving in all directions randomly. For the entire system (the car) to move, a predominant direction has to appear in the randomness of atomic thermal vibration - and that happens gradually (i.e., from the very moment the clutch is engaged, or whatever system the vehicle is equipped with).
So gradually in fact, that in order to decide on the exact moment the movement starts, you need to decide on what level of analysis to apply to the system, and which exactly of the small perturbations initiates the change of velocity of "the car".

Most of the other answers are quite thoughtful and precise. No doubt, more educational than this one. Even so, perhaps a simpler interpretation could be useful.
Assuming the "calculus" and "differentiation" tags were not added by the author of the original post, this strikes me as, potentially, an introductory physics question.
Consider a high school level physics course concerned with an introduction to Newtonian physics. The question may have been (albeit composed with some imprecision in language) attempting to extract a specific answer from the student.
Perhaps it was merely designed to elicit a response such as:
"A force was applied"
One thing taught in such a course is "Objects at rest tend to stay at rest". So how could the car's movement be explained if not for the application of a force?
All of this is speculation of course, based on my own experience in high school.

I think the answer is called "wind-up", probably measured in milliseconds.
When an automobile sits on a level surface, there exist various clearances between gears, universal joints and splines between the differential transmission and the driven axles of the vehicle.  The crank shaft needs to make a partial revolution to take up the slack before the wheels start to turn.  In addition, the torque applied to the drive shaft and other shafts in the power train adds another degree or so the rotation of the crank shaft to start the vehicle moving.

If we rephrase the question as 'what happens between the last moment the tyre contact point is at rest and the first moment the tyre contact point moves?' the issue of "wind up" time becomes irrelevant.

This question reveals a shortcoming of the naive zero-duration interactions between objects.
In the most naive model we have one block sitting still and another moving towards it. At some special moment $t_0$ they collide and there is a transfer of momentum. The velocities instantaneously change meaning the objects experience infinite acceleration for a zero-length duration.
Physics abhors infinities.
A more sophisticated model models the two blocks as squishy. They are like two springs. When the one box approaches the other, eventually it makes contact. The two springs compress a little bit over a finite amount of time, some momentum is transferred, then the blocks stop touching with the end result being a momentum transfer. The springs might ring a little bit even after the collision. This would be evidence of an inelastic collision.
But that model still has the problem where initially the springs are uncompressed and then instantaneously they feel a rapid change in their rate of compression. This is again an infinity.
A more sophisticated model considers the electromagnetic repulsion felt between the objects due to the objects that constitute them. In this case the force between the objects follows a Lennard-Jones potential so that even at large distances there is a super small but still non-zero force between the two objects. As they get closer the force gets larger until the distance between is on order of the interatomic spacing. Then the force rapidly, but smoothly, ramps up between the two objects. The lattices will compress some like in the previous model, and there will be a net transfer of momentum like in the original model.
It this model everything is smooth. There is no special moment $t_0$. There is a brief, but finite, period of time when the particles are experiencing a large repulsive force due to the repulsive part of the Lennard-Jones potential, but all of the physical variables evolve smoothly regardless of what special $t_0$ you might pick. There is no paradox. Just smooth Hamiltonian evolution.

"Paradoxes" like these are usually resolved by remembering that nature abhors an infinity and figuring out how to make your model more sophisticated to get around the infinity.

As other answers have pointed out, this is an age-old form of query, but modern mathematics considers it to be a solved problem.
The most common answer I am aware of (and there are many different answers) is that there is no last moment the car is stationary.  To make this argument, we start from the assumption that the motion of the car can be defined by function that accepts a real number, time, and outputs a boolean value, indicating whether it moves or not.  Let $t_0$ be the first time where this function shows that the car moves. With this construction, we can define a Dedekind Cut, partitioning the real numbers into two subsets.  One subset  contains all times less than $t_0$ and the other contains the remaining real numbers.  It can be shown that the first subset has no greatest element: there is no last time that a the car is stationary.  This is provable with a proof by contradiction.
There are other answers.  As one other answer here pointed out, one may disagree with the original assumption above.  Instead, one may use another number system, such as the hyperreals, which leads to different answers,

The above answers fail to remember that reality is quantized at teeny-tiny scales.
Even with ideal, platonic objects, if 2 of them touch and then later, they don't touch, THEN:
There exists a time such that the objects touched, then 1E-37 secs later, they do not touch anymore. That's called the plank time. Nothing can happen faster than that.
Zeno's paradox does not appply in physical reality because both space and time are quantized.
"The question is: what happens between these 2 moments?"
If the moments are 1 planck time apart, there IS no "between these 2 moments."

I'm pretty sure what you are saying about Planck time is a misconception.  The Planck time gives a limit to our theoretical measurement accuracy due to the uncertainty principle, but it does not imply that time does not exist at scales below that.  Same with Planck Length.

@JMac As Hawking once said, " Wrong again, Albert." No event below the plank limit can be distinguished from any other event which is closer than that to it (in 4 dimensions). They are the same event.

The inability to measure such things is due to the inherent uncertainty of our measurements.  That does not mean that events cannot occur in less time than that, or that things can occur in sequence in less time.  It just means we dont have a feasible way to measure it because we know any measurement will inherently effect the system we were trying to measure in a way that interferes with measurement.

@jmac Make sure you don't get it backwards. It's not the case that there is detail below the planck limit, but we just can't see it because of uncertainty. No. In fact, there is no detail below the planck limit. It's like zooming in on a photograph until it turns blury, and then it's a single color pixel.  There is no more information hidden in he image.

I think you need to provide some good sources for that, because practically everything I've read besides some over-simplified pop-sci has said otherwise.  The idea of "quantum foam" for example, is basically the opposite of what you're describing where things become like a single colour pixel at that scale.

@JMac Ok, believe that things happen faster than the planck time, but you just don't notice them. Believe that 2 objects can be smaller than the planck size, but we just can't resolve them because it's impossible to build a microscope that small. Believe that, it's okay with me.

I will believe that's a possibility, because the science hasn't ruled it out at all.  I think it's a much more honest way to approach science than to rule things out without providing good reasons/evidence.

Because I dont believe random unsourced posts here that go against a majority of the scientific information I can find...? 10/10 great logic.

@JMac So you think the majority of scientific lit says there's information below the planck limit but we just can't see it. Yeah, that's fine 'n dandy.

@KDP The point is that discrete times and places are possible only above a certain scale. Below that scale you can't use stage magic tricks like Zeno's paradox.

@MissUnderstands I am interested in your opinion on the distinction between a minimum discrete length and a minimum discrete time interval. For example consider a particle with a velocity of 0.25c. Does it wait for 4 Plank intervals and then instantly move forward one plank length, or does it move forward a 1/4 Planck length every plank time interval?

If we have a unit square with sides of one Plank length, what is the length of the diagonal?

@KDP "a unit square with sides of one Plank length" === There can be no such grid at that scale. The "gridness"fades out — the abiliy to distinguish different points. It's exactly the same fallacy as thinking of Infinity as just a very large integer, larger than any other.

@MissUnderstands How is infinity an analogy at all here?  If I think of infinity as a very very large integer, no matter the size, I can double it and still be less than infinity.  Planck length is nothing like that.  It has a numerical value already.

@JMac AACK! I can see how that wouldn't make sense. I really screwed up the analogy, but I'll explain what I was thinking even though it doesn't matter. Infinite length is thought of as a (large) finite distance when It really never ends, whereas a planck length is a smallest length, but you think there are infinitely-smaller ones, when there aren't. Like I said, I screwed it up.
